# Not able to create react native project with "npx react-native init SampleApp"

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a React Native project by running the below command but getting error message **missing ) after argument list**

```
******:ReactNative admin$ npx react-native init SampleApp
**missing ) after argument list**
```

I'm following the steps mentioned here:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Please provide any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution. I was using the older version for Node.js(Version 8.xx) and now I updated it with 12.13.0 which resolved the problem.